# Расшифровка email из непонятной кодировки

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Друзья, произвожу парсинг одного сайта при помощи библиотеки simple html dom. Но случилась такая ситуация, maail на сайте отображается в данном виде

```
string(90) "mailto:%72o%6di%6b%2d%73%63%6f%72p%69%6fn@%79%61n%64%65%78.ru"
```

Если смотреть через "Исходный вид страницы" то тег a записан таким образом

```
<a href="mail&#116;o:%72o%6d%69%6b%2ds%63or%70%69o%6e@y%61nd%65x.ru"  title="">&#114;&#111;&#109;&#105;&#107;&#45;sc&#111;&#114;pio&#110;@&#121;&#97;&#110;d&#101;&#120;.&#114;&#117;</a>
```

Как я понял название ссылки зашифровано в ascii, но сама ссылка почему то отличается, хотя в обоих случаях зашифрован romik-scorpion@yandex.ru

С таким я ни разу не сталкивался, может можно как то расшифровать их при помощи php?

Comment: Почему непонятная, в % hex номер символа в таблице ASCII, а в &# dec-номер символа в таблице ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[URL кодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL):

> Стандарт URL использует набор символов US-ASCII. Это имеет серьёзный недостаток, поскольку разрешается использовать лишь латинские буквы, цифры и несколько знаков пунктуации. Все другие символы необходимо перекодировать. Например, перекодироваться должны буквы кириллицы, буквы с диакритическими знаками, лигатуры, иероглифы. Перекодирующая кодировка описана в стандарте RFC 3986 и называется URL-encoding, URLencoded или percent‐encoding.

Что бы декодировать Вашу ссылку надо использовать [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)

```
<?php
 var_dump(urldecode('%72o%6d%69%6b%2ds%63or%70%69o%6e@y%61nd%65x.ru'));
```

Comment: Вот я не сторонник жестокости, но этих парсеров, как и тех кто им раболепно помогает, сажал бы на кол.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а чем они вас довели?

Comment: @Ипатьев или идеологическая неприязнь? :)